# Empty buffer when reading from a QTcpSocket

Tags: qt, qtnetwork, qtcore

I am creating a simple threaded TCP server (based on the threaded Fortune server example).  I have connected the readyRead signal to my readCommand slot, and I confirmed that the readCommand function fires after I've telnetted to my server and sent a string (followed by enter).

The function below outputs "In readCommand" once I send the string HELLO, then the output "new inBuffer" always shows empty ("").

```
void FortuneThread::readCommand()
{
    qDebug() << "in readCommand" << endl;
    QDataStream in(tcpSocketPtr);
    in.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_0);
    in >> inBuffer;
    qDebug() << "new inBuffer: " << inBuffer << endl;
    ...
}
```

If I print out tcpSocket->bytesAvailable(), then I see a growing count of characters as I send more via telnet.  I'm just not getting them out of the socket...the code above is copied from the Fortune Client example so I assumed it would work. Am I using QDataStream wrong?

Comment: I am not sure Michelle, but why are you using "QDataStream::Qt_4_0". Which Qt version are you using? Also, is the tcp socket ptr a class member of FortuneThread?

Comment: Do you see the proper length when sending data as opposed to checking whether it is growing?

Comment: I copied Qt_4_0 directly from their example...but I don't think it matters since the other end (client) is not encoding, just sending characters via telnet.  If I connect from the telnet client, type HELLO and enter, the byte count grows to 7 (which I assume means my client sent /n/r, or maybe a null on the end?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You should not initialize your QDataStream with QTcpSocket.
- You should read the data from the socket io device with `QByteArray QIODevice::readAll()`.
- You should write the byte array of the previous operation into the data stream with the "<<" operator.

So, the code should look something like this:

```
void FortuneThread::readCommand()
{
    QByteArray block;
    QDataStream out(&block, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    out << tcpSocketPtr->readAll();
    ...
}
```

Comment: I think you're onto something here.  I remove the QDataStream and can now access the characters.  I think your solution is a bit more complex than I need thought, but thanks.

Comment: How do you read from a write on device?

Answer (score 0):

The codes like these would work:

```
QByteArray res;
res.reserve(m_tcp_socket_ptr->bytesAvailable());
res = m_tcp_socket_ptr->readAll();

qDebug() << res;
```